# Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found

Tags: php, slim

Hello I really need help with this error I get when working with SLIM. I get this error:

```
Type: Error
Message: Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found
File: /storage/content/90/223690/marbleuf.se/public_html/cart/app/Validation/Forms/OrderForm.php
Line: 12
```

Here is my code from OrderForm.php:

```
<?php

namespace Cart\Validation\Forms;

use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

class OrderForm
{
    public static function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => v::email(),
            'name' => v::alpha(' '),
            'address1' => v::alnum(' -'),
            'address2' => v::optional(v::alnum(' -')),
            'city' => v::alnum(' '),
            'postal_code' => v::alnum(' '),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what else we can tell you - the class you're trying to `use` isn't found. Is it autoloaded?

Comment: How do I autoload it? Please no hate im new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my assumption your use statement should be the following

```
use Cart\Validation\Validator as v;
```

NOT

```
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;
```

See this for reference (If I have the right code base) https://github.com/raniesantos/slim-cart/blob/master/app/Validation/Validator.php

Comment: Type: Error
Message: Call to undefined method Cart\Validation\Validator::email()
File: /storage/content/90/223690/marbleuf.se/public_html/cart/app/Validation/Forms/OrderForm.php
Line: 12